# Swift 3.0 down casting and best practices

Tags: swift

My question here is mostly in trying to be a better programmer, not that my code doesn't work.

Is downcasting something considered good enough (as in 'best practices') when writing your code? I'll give an example below with URLSession. I understand Swift gives you the tools to do it with as! or as?, but something tells me we shouldn't be doing it (or there are better ways to do it). I just can't see them. For example, consider this code that retrieves a web page from a HTTP GET request:

```
guard let url = URL(string: apiEndpoint) else {
    return
}
if let scheme = url.scheme {
    if scheme !=  "http" || scheme != "https" {
        return
    }
}
// More code
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let err = error {
        // Error handling here
    }
    else {
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            return
        }
        // Code here
    }
}.resume()
```

So, the above code works, but my question is on the `guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse` statement. `dataTask` is supposed to return an `URLResponse` object back to the delegate, in this case, my variable `response`. However, this class obviously doesn't have a status code. So if I do the following, Swift will give me a compile error:

```
guard let httpResponse = response else {
    return nil
}
statusCode = response.statusCode
```

Because `response` is supposed to be an URLResponse object, so it fails Xcode's check.

In order to obtain that information I need to either force down casting to HTTPURLResponse with as! (I've checked that the request is http/https earlier) or check with an optional as I did above.

Now, I don't want to use big wrappers like Alamofire because my API is very very simple. I want to write my own wrapper around URLResponse and return an object that other parts of my code can use. I don't know how the AF guys solve this problem. What would be the Swift way of dealing with this? Is down casting fine as a "best practice"? Is there a better way of getting the HTTPURLResponse object?

Comment: Your variable naming is off: Should't it be `guard let **response** = r as? HTTPURLResponse`? Also, `(d, r, e)` is alittle bit too cryptic. Switching to `(data, response, error)` goes a long way making your code readable.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I usually don't like assigning "high value names" to variables I won't use on more than one line of code. Those are the optional returns from the completion handler that I need to unpack. As I replied below, notice how `e` becomes `error` when unwrapped, `r` becomes `request` and `d` becomes `dataString`. I could use something like `errorOptional`, `requestOptional` and `dataOptional`, but I guess it was just a choice at the time (their explanation in on a comment block on my original code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, strictly spoken a block based API doesn't have a delegate.

`URLSessionDataTask` is a quite versatile class and can be used for other purposes than an HTTP request hence the response object is the more generic `URLResponse` class and it is optional.

In case of an HTTP request the API returns the more specific subclass `HTTPURLResponse` so the object **must** be casted down to get access to the specific properties of `HTTPURLResponse` like `statusCode`. So yes, ***down casting is fine as a "best practice"***.

Here are two suggestions *to be a better programmer*

1. Variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter e.g. `urlString`
2. As already mentioned in a comment use more descriptive variable names than a single character.

There is another serious error in the code: The completion handler has no return value so you will get a compiler error *Unexpected non-void return value in void function*.

Side-note: The check for the scheme and for `nil` is not needed since the literal string `https://www.google.com` clearly contains the scheme and is a valid URL.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I am sorry, my bad, I meant URLResponse. I've edited my original post so it is correct now for future reference.

Comment: I know that URLSessionDataTask is very versatile, hence why I am writing a simpler wrapper around it for my application. What maybe wasn't clear from my original post is that I used that code as an example. So: 1 - my function does return nil. 2 - I gave Google as an obvious example, in my code that would be a variable (which is why I need to check for the scheme). 3 - The "cryptic" variables are meant to be unwrapped into more readable and clear variables. Check how `e` becomes `error` when unwrapped, `r` becomes `request` and `d` becomes `data`.

Comment: In my original code I have comments on those lines to reflect this choice. I'm also not using a block in my original code, but a real delegate. The code pasted here is meant only as an example, since my real question revolved around a single line of all that code.

Comment: No offense but if you want a specific answer post real code rather than sample code which doesn't even compile.

Comment: OK, thank you. Real code was much much more than that. In my original post I had pasted only that one line `guard let request = r as? HTTPURLResponse else`. Then I changed my mind and wrote that block around it for context (on why I was down casting to HTTPURLResponse in the first place). Do you think my question would be better if I edited it all and left only that one line? Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: As you accepted the answer and therefore regard the question as answered just leave the question as it is.